# MySQL - ORDER BY Rand() always gives the same result

Tags: mysql

I have a query that selects and groups random records like below:

```
SELECT PRDT_CODE FROM (
    SELECT * FROM CTGR
    INNER JOIN PRDT on PRDT.PRDT_CTGR = CTGR.CTGR_CODE AND PRDT.PRDT_STUS = 'A'
    INNER JOIN PFIL on PFIL.PFIL_PRDT = PRDT.PRDT_CODE AND PFIL.PFIL_MAIN = 1
    ORDER BY RAND()
) A
GROUP BY CTGR_CODE
LIMIT 4;
```

The same query is executed on MySQL Workbench and PhpMyAdmin.

The result set gotten from the Workbench is completely random (which is something I want). On the other hand, PhpMyAdmin returns the same result set despite the `ORDER BY RAND()` keyword is being used.

Any idea why this is happening?

**EDIT**

Results in Workbench:

1st run:
[image]

2nd run:
[image]

Results in PMA:

1st run:
[image]

2nd run:
[image]

**Expected output: the result set from Workbench;**

**Actual output: the result set from PMA**

Comment: It might be caching the results. You can run some query to temporary disable caching.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Tried using `SQL_NO_CACHE`, as well as selecting an additional column of `NOW()`.

Comment: Maybe the optimizer kicks in. How about trying to trick it with something like SELECT *, RAND() AS rnd FROM CTGR ..... ORDER BY rnd ?

Comment: Still doesn't work. Again, the same thing works on Workbench but not on PMA

Comment: update  your question, adda proper data sample  your actual  result and your expected  result  .. (the use of group by without aggreagtion function can produce unpredicatble result)

Comment: using MySQL 5.6 `RAND()` is very inefficient; it's processor heavy, it's not actually very random ; if you really want fast random results you can mix things up in the output script rather than the data collection point.

Comment: Most likely your use of `GROUP BY` is causing this. What is it you are trying to achieve with the `GROUP BY`? You should use `GROUP BY` only when you have a query mixing normal columns with aggregate functions.

Comment: Say, I have 10 categories, each with 10 different items. I would like to randomly select 4 categories with 1 random item each. Hence, the use of `GROUP BY` to eliminate the other "records" from the result of `INNER JOIN` clause

Answer (score 0):

Try using the order by in the out query

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM CTGR
    INNER JOIN PRDT on PRDT.PRDT_CTGR = CTGR.CTGR_CODE AND PRDT.PRDT_STUS = 'A'
    INNER JOIN PFIL on PFIL.PFIL_PRDT = PRDT.PRDT_CODE AND PFIL.PFIL_MAIN = 1
    ) A
GROUP BY CTGR_CODE
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 4;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this only randomizes the order of the end result of the SAME dataset.